# Issue with Chaining jQuery animations in callback

Tags: jquery

so I think this should be really simple but I am not sure what I am missing.  I have a DIV that I want to fade out, then change some text, and then fade back in.

It sort of works, but it does the text update then the fade out and fade in, although I thought I had the chaining correct.

Here is the basic code

```
<div id="box" style="width:300px;height:200px;background-color:yellow">
    <span id="game">Game 1</span>
    <br/>
    <a href="javaScript:ChangeGame()">Next Game</a>
</div>

window.game = 1;

window.ChangeGame = function ()
{
    $("#box")
        .fadeOut(1000, nextGame()).fadeIn();

}

window.nextGame = function() {
    $("#game").text("Game " + game++);
}
```

and here is a jsFiddle that shows the problem

http://jsfiddle.net/mdq6f/4/

Thanks for your help kind folk

Comment: `()` after a function reference always *calls* the function.

Comment: Why this: 'window.ChangeGame = function (){...}' when you could simply write 'function ChangeGame() {...} for more readability?

Comment: Also, I would rewrite your ChageGame function so that when the user clicks multiple times on the link before the fadeOut is complete you avoid the 'yoyo' effect.

Comment: @frenchie I added it like that just to get jsfiddle to work.  There is probably a better way

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: look into the .on() and .off() functions to avoid the multiple click problem you have. You need to unwire the handler on the click event and then rewire the event just as the fadeIn function starts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `nextGame()` to `nextGame`:

```
$("#box")
    .fadeOut(1000, nextGame).fadeIn();
```

You were calling the function directly instead of just *pointing* to it.

In case you need to provide some arguments to `nextGame` you need to wrap it into an anonomous function:

```
$("#box")
    .fadeOut(1000, function() { 
        nextGame(/* enter arguments as you wish */); 
    })
    .fadeIn();
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you.  Bonus points for second guessing that I needed to pass arguments as indeed I did.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$("#box").fadeOut(1000, nextGame).fadeIn();
```

instead of

```
$("#box").fadeOut(1000, nextGame()).fadeIn();
```

using `nextGame()` in callback calls the function immediately on executing the above line, rather than passing on the function to be called after fadeIn is complete.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.ChangeGame = function () {
    $("#box").fadeOut(1000, nextGame).fadeIn(1000);
}
```

Will do what you want and perform the fade In and Out at equal speeds.